# Get clicked button's id by class name without jquery

Tags: javascript

I don't want to use jquery for this small task.

### HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="button" id="btn_1" class="cls_btn" value="Click Me" />
    <input type="button" id="btn_2" class="cls_btn" value="Click Me" />
    <input type="button" id="btn_3" class="cls_btn" value="Click Me" />
</form>
```

### **javascript**

I want id of button when it clicked.
my js code looks like

```
<script >
    document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn').onclick = function(){
        alert(this.id);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of DOM elements so you need to loop it and add an event listener to each:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVy4q/)

Comment: I had two buttons, so I did without a loop: `var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn');buttons[0].addEventListener('click', function(){alert(this.id);});buttons[1].addEventListener('click', function() {alert(this.id);})` Still valid in 2021 - IT is progressing slowly;)

Answer (score 9):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of DOM objects. Applying `.onclick` to a collection of html items results in nothing. No error is thrown but you'll not see the expected result anyway.

Try this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){ alert(this.id) };
}
```

See here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9yMf/2/)

---

> I don't want to use jquery for this small task.

Note that jQuery can handle the same loop for you. No need to iterate over the list: just provide the selector and it will be done for you.

```
$('.cls_btn').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

See here: [JSFiddle (jq)](http://jsfiddle.net/J9yMf/3/)

Comment: I know how to find id by class name in jquery. Why I use jquery only for this task ?

Comment: I didn't told you have to use jQuery. I just provided both solutions for you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You need to loop over this to add the onlcick handler to each item:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(this.id);
    };
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/RjUvQ/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this | No jquery [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjZ6N/)

```
window.onload=function(){
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn');
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
        addEventHandler(ele[i],'click',doWhatever);
    }
}
function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
 if (elem.addEventListener) // for rest of browsers
     elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
 else if (elem.attachEvent) // for IE
     elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}
function doWhatever()
{
  // do whaterver you want
  alert(this.id);   
}
```